# Existence of limit of two variables

Tags: limits, polar-coordinates

According to wolfram alpha math If $f(x,y)=ylog|x| where\ x,y\ are\ real$ then $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)= 0 $$ now if we change the given function into polar coordintes then its limit will also be $0$ . i.e, $$\lim_{r\to 0^+}r(sin\theta) log|rcos\theta|=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ .......(1)$$. now the main question is if: $$g(x,y)=|x|^y$$ then its limit at origin is : calculating the limit along the curve $x=e^{(-k/y)}$ as $$\lim_{y\to 0}g(e^{-k/y},y)= \lim_{y\to 0}|e^{(-k/y)}|^y$$ $$\lim_{y\to 0}e^{-k}= 1/e^k$$ means it depends on the value of k. hence limit of $g$ does not exists at origin. BUT THE MAIN PROBLEM IS THAT IF WE CHANGE INTO POLAR COORDINATES THEN CALCULATE ITS LIMIT $$\lim_{r\to 0^+}|rcos\theta|^{rsin\theta}$$ which is $0^0 form$ hence , we write it as $$e^{\lim_{r\to 0^+}r(sin\theta)log|rcos\theta|}$$ from $(1)$ $$\lim_{r\to 0^+}r(sin\theta) log|rcos\theta|=0 $$ therefore $$e^0=1$$ thus by coordinates its limit is unique and finite. which contradicts the limit along curve method. can anyone tell me $$\lim_{r\to 0^+}r(sin\theta) log|rcos\theta|=0$$ it is true or not? if it is false then it contradicts the limit of $f(x,y)=ylog|x|$ **can anyone explain it ?**

Comment: Everyone knows it f is not defined at x=0, but its limit is zero at origin

Comment: You may check it on wolframalpha math

Comment: Ok, comment was not relevant

Comment: @Daniel can you explain it

Comment: However, you should trust a little less in Wolfram alpha. Your example of approaching zero through $(e^{-k/y}, y)$ with $y > 0$ shows the limit of $f(x,y)$ when $(x,y) \to 0$ does not exist.

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora **what** "its limit at zero is zero" ? And you cannot take the sequence $\;\left\{\left(e^{-k/y},\,y\right)\right\}\;$ to approach the origin as the first coordinate does *not* approach zero when $\;y\to0\;$ ...

Comment: Limit of f is zer0 and of g is does not exist at origin

Comment: @Daniel didn't get your explanation, please clarify it

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora Assuming $\;k>0\;$ :  $$\lim_{y\to0^-}e^{-k/y}=\infty\;,\;\lim_{y\to0^+}e^{-k/y}=0$$ and thus yor calculating the limit along that curve is invalid as the sequence itself does **not** converge to $\;(0,0)\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio as i already know the limit of g does not exist, but whats wrong with the function f , Is limit of f at origin is zero or not. If not then prove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}y\ln(|x|)$ doesn't exist since

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,\frac{k}{\ln(|x|)})=k$$

Comment: Can wolfram math may be wrong?

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora Of course. if you use polar coordinates, what about the case $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: I also know that at theta tends to pi/2 the epression tends to -infinity and the function is not bounded. So the limit does not exist of f. But wolfram alpha gave 0.